# Apostrophes in UI (', ’) which is correct?

Tags: support, bug, design, spelling

I just noticed that in site UI at least two types of apostrophes are used:

1. `’`
2. `'`

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) the first one is called *"Typesetter's apostrophe"* and the second one is *"Typewriter apostrophe"*.

<sub>(This is funny that the name of the first one contains the second type of apostrophe.)</sub>

I didn't count all of them (since the traducir limitations), but [searching for `’s`](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%E2%80%99s) returns 158 strings and [searching for `'s`](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%27s) return 198 strings.

All these strings are used in site's user interface. Should we use only one type of apostrophe in the same cases or using both interchangeably is normal for UI elements?

N.B. Interestingly that searching for any type of apostrophe via browser (Firefox in particular) accepts both of them.

Comment: I always thought that character is just "single quote". Turns out it's much more complex, lol.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard which one character?

Comment: 'this' one, where "this" is the double quote. Simple. Then I started seeing apostrophe words used, and kind of got lost in all of it. Still can't really figure which is which, so I generally ignore it. :)